# android cannot get download file

Tags: java, android, url

I currently using eclipse and xampp to do my android assignment, I have a code to download the txt file in my localhot folder, however it keep saying

```
java.io.EOFException
```

This is my folder directory, inside this directory got 1 txt file called movie queue.txt

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\android\uploads\u0001\public
```

This is my url

```
  String url = "http://10.0.2.2/android/uploads/u0001/public/movie%20queue.txt
```

This is the code

```
     URL u = new URL(url);
     URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
     int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();
     DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(u.openStream());
     byte[] buffer = new byte[contentLength];
     stream.readFully(buffer);
     stream.close();
     DataOutputStream fos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dest_file));
     fos.write(buffer);
     fos.flush();
     fos.close();
```

The error happen at

```
     URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
     int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();
```

Can help me solve it?

Comment: Are you sure that url is correct? - it doesn't look like it. EOF generally means there's something wrong with the file you're trying to get.

Comment: Where you are having this file It's in your same sd cared in your server

Comment: @sihrc cause i am using XAMPP on my computer, i can login by sending request to http://10.0.2.2/android/login.php. So i am sure http://10.0.2.2 is a valid address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure and i found the error you just save your file name without the space and the you download the file it will download definitely Because am also had this problem You just upload the file without space in file name and download it....

```
http://10.0.2.2/android/uploads/u0001/public/movie**%20**queue.txt
```

**In this %20 is mentioning the space** So you will upload and download it will the solution..All the best